# Is the Jackson2JsonMessageConverter class thread-safe?

Tags: java, spring, thread-safety, spring-amqp

I'm using this class and I'm wondering whether it's thread safe:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/support/converter/Jackson2JsonMessageConverter.html

The docs don't make any claims about this. I skipped through the code and found no signs it's **not** thread-safe. It's using an `ObjectMapper` internally, which **is** thread-safe according to docs:

https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.13/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html

> Mapper instances are fully thread-safe provided that ALL configuration of the instance occurs before ANY read or write calls.

So I would *assume* that `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` is thread-safe, as long as I don't change any configuration before doing any operation.

Comment: I've never had any multithreading issues with it, it'd be quite useless if it wasn't thread safe, no?

Comment: "Useless", I don't know, you could still create a new instance before each conversion. I agree that it *should* be thread-safe, but I'm looking for an "Yes, it is, because x, y, ..." answer. I found that kind of answer for `ObjectMapper`, but unfortunately not for this class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't change any properties of the `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` at runtime, then it is indeed thread-safe. It is always unpredictable for the next message to convert if new value for properties are going to have effect not. In general most of components in the framework are thread-safe since they are stateless as long as you don't change the component configuration at runtime.